# Update table rows with data from second table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am trying to update specific rows in a master table from data in a secondary table.

I have a master table of 100,000 rows with a number of columns one of which is "UniqueCode", a unique Alpha Code and another is "Data", which contains a string of text . I have a smaller secondary table of about 2,000 rows with 2 columns, "New_Data" and "Code". "New data" is another string and "Code" is Alpha Code which is equal to a "UniqueCode" from the Master Table.

I want to update  the column "Data" in the Master table when the Alpha Code from the secondary table is equal to the Alpha Code from the Master table and set it to be the same as "New_data" from the secondary table.

Would appreciate any help with this as struggling to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE MasterTable
SET 
    Data = s.New_Data
FROM MasterTable m
INNER JOIN SecondaryTable s ON m.UniqueCode = s.Code
```

Comment: Does SQL 2000 support such syntax?

Comment: @abatishchev : what exactly confusing you? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: I haven't got an instance in from on me to check, but from memory, this is valid SQL Server 2000 code.

Comment: Perfect, it's supported and does exactly what I needed. Thanks @sll

Answer (score 1):

```
update master
set data = s.new_data
from master m
inner join second s on m.alphacode = s.code
```

or

```
update master
set data = s.new_data
from master m, second s
where m.alphacode = s.code
```